# Oracle PL-SQL : Import multiple delimited files into table

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, plsql, delimited

I have multiple files (f1.log, f2.log, f3.log etc)
Each file has the data in `;` & `=` delimited format. (new lines are delimited by `;` and fields are delimited by `=`) e.g.

data of f1:

```
1=a;2=b;3=c
```

data of f2:

```
1=p;2=q;3=r
```

I need to read all these files and import data into table in format:

```
filename  number  data

f1        1       a

f1        2       b

f1        3       c

f2        1       p
[...]
```

I am new to SQL. Can you please guide me, how can do it?

Comment: u looking for sqlldr control file syntax maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SQL*Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm) to get the files into a table. Assuming you have a table created a bit like:

```
create table FLOG
(
  FILENAME   varchar2(1000)
 ,NUM        varchar2(1000)
 ,DATA       varchar2(1000)
);
```

Then you can use the following control file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'f1.log' "str ';'"
truncate INTO TABLE flog
fields terminated by '=' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
   filename constant 'f1'
   ,num  char 
   ,data char 
)
```

However, you will need a different control file for each file. This can be done by making the control file dynamically using a shell script. A sample shell script can be:

```
cat >flog.ctl <<_EOF
LOAD DATA
INFILE '$1.log' "str ';'"
APPEND INTO TABLE flog
fields terminated by '=' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
filename constant '$1'
,num  char
,data char
)
_EOF

sqlldr <username>/<password>@<instance> control=flog.ctl data=$1.log
```

Saved as `flog.sh` it can then be run like:

```
./flog.sh f1
./flog.sh f2
```

Comment: Dear John, Thank you very much for your answer. I have couple of queries:
1) What is the purpose of putting ""str ';'" after INFILE?
2) I can not use shell script, as I have only windows here. How can I generate dynamic control file for each and every data file that I am parsing? I thought of spooling files inside procedure. But that is not possible as spooling can not be done inside procedures.
3)If while executing sqlldr, we are using 'data=' option, do we have to use INFILE clause inside ctl file? As per my understanding they both serve the same purpose.

Comment: The `"str ';'"` indicates that `;` is the record separator, not newline (`str` stands for `stream`). The `INFILE` line is still needed because of that though the filename part is now superfluous as the `data=` command line option will always overwrite what is there. But a filename still needs to be placed after `INFILE` - you can get away with any name though. I'm not too familiar with Windows batch files so I've asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9121876/64921) to see if my script can be converted.

Comment: Dear John,  Thank you very much for your kind help. Actually my requirement is little bit different. I have blob data, which is in format of files f1, f2 as explained above. my code looks like:  `for loop  -- procedure called below, generates text files f1.log, f2.log<br/> proc_to_read_blob(filename)  /*code which loads data in files f1.log, f2.log into DB table*/  proc_to_pars_files(filename)  end for loop`  I do not wish to use batch or shell script, as I wish to make this code generic for different OS'. Not really sure how to use sqlldr in this scenario :(

Comment: I apologize for incorrect formatting. I tried to correct it may times, but it does not seem to be working on my local machine.