# Convert Unix Shell Script to Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I have a shell script (.sh) that works in Unix but I'd like to convert it into a Windows batch file (.bat):

```
cat >flog.ctl <<_EOF
LOAD DATA
INFILE '$1.log' "str ';'"
APPEND INTO TABLE flog
fields terminated by '=' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
filename constant '$1'
,num  char
,data char
)
_EOF

sqlldr <username>/<password>@<instance> control=flog.ctl data=$1.log
```

I'm not too knowledgable on batch files but if an answer is some hints rather than a complete solution then I'm sure I'll muddle through. This is to help with an answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9112209/64921).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows batch files do not support inlining data this way. You'll have to

```
ECHO firstLine > flog.ctl
ECHO additionalLine >> flog.ctl
```

Windows batch files denote variables in ECHO statements using % signs, i.e. %1%.

So you're resulting file would be something like:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO LOAD DATA > flog.ctl
ECHO INFILE '%1%.log' "str ';'" >> flog.ctl
ECHO APPEND INTO TABLE flog >> flog.ctl
ECHO fields terminated by '=' TRAILING NULLCOLS >> flog.ctl
ECHO ( >> flog.ctl
ECHO filename constant '%1%' >> flog.ctl
ECHO ,num  char >> flog.ctl
ECHO ,data char >> flog.ctl
ECHO ) >> flog.ctl

sqlldr <username>/<password>@<instance> control=flog.ctl data=%1%.log
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `%1%` and `%1` as used in @voithos's code? I've tested both and both work.

Comment: @JohnDoyle: The second % is not necessary. I think James might be used to using two signs to delimit variables in batch files, [like shown here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/630/using-variables-in-windows-batch-files/). But the "correct" way to reference command line arguments, as far as I know, is to [use a single %](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm#02).

Comment: Hi, @JohnDoyle. Neither way is more correct than the other. It's true that you can always reference the argument variables 0-9 with a single % because they get special treatment when expanded. I make always using the second % a habit because when using named variables, `ECHO %Asometext%B` will have the wrong output and `ECHO %A%sometext%B%` will not. Give it a try some time and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @voithos See my comment above.

Comment: @James: I still prefer the single %. The double % works because command-line arguments get mapped to environment variables of the same name. I like differentiating between arguments and environment variables, and I know of at least one reason to do so: `%*` can be used a shorthand for "all the arguments", whereas `%*%` is an error, and will just give *. In short, even though you can use either one most of the time, they're not equivalent.

Comment: powershell supports inlining like this with [herestrings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There *are* some complicated solutions as far as the inlining goes, but as was already mentioned, a simple solution would be to use `echo`.

```
@echo off

echo LOAD DATA > flog.ctl
echo INFILE '%1.log' "str ';'" >> flog.ctl
echo APPEND INTO TABLE flog >> flog.ctl
echo fields terminated by '=' TRAILING NULLCOLS >> flog.ctl
echo ( >> flog.ctl
echo filename constant '%1' >> flog.ctl
echo ,num  char >> flog.ctl
echo ,data char >> flog.ctl
echo ) >> flog.ctl

sqlldr <username>/<password>@<instance> control=flog.ctl data=%1.log
```